# Automating selection in Javascript-generated type-ahead drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, python, drop-down-menu, selenium-rc, keypress

I am writing a script to automate the filling out of a form using Selenium RC for python. One of the input fields has an AJAX type-ahead estimator that generates a drop-down list of suggestions as you type. I would like to select the first option, but since there is no HTML representation of the dynamically generated list, I have tried simulating pressing "Enter", simulating a mouse click away from the menu, and moving the focus to a different element, all which work manually on a browser (and result in an autosave that generates new information on the page). However, when I run the following code on the Selenium server, the dropdown menu stubbornly stays there and no selection/autosave/update occurs:

```
    sel.focus('otherelement')
    sel.key_press('element', '\13') # As far as I know, 13 is the keycode for the "Enter" key
    sel.key_press_native('\13') # I also tried 'KeyEvent.VK_ENTER' since that is apparently the keycode for a java.awt.event.KeyEvent 
    sel.click('title')
    sel.mouse_out('element')
    sel.mouse_down_at('element', '10,20')
    sel.mouse_up_at('element', '10,20')
```

All of these were tested separately and collectively, to no avail. Does anybody have any corrections/suggestions?

**EDIT:** The following worked for the site I was testing (solution probably varies from site to site):

```
    sel.mouse_down('element')
    sel.mouse_up('element')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code that i tried on google page

```
    sel = self.selenium
    sel.open("http://www.google.co.in/")
    sel.type_keys("q", "vi")
    time.sleep(2)
    sel.key_down("q", "\\40")
    sel.key_up("q", "\\40")
    sel.key_press("q", "\\13")
```

Comment: When you are moving down, is the text on which you are scrolling is seen in the text box ? For the case it doesn't work for this case after scrolling down use space to select the scrolled label/text. For Space use \\32 Key code.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to press enter. I haven't seen it done successfully via selenium RC using key_down or key_press etc in Python.

Comment: try     sel.key_down("q", "\\13")
        sel.key_up("q", "\\13") to press enter

Comment: yep, I did (though for a jQuery text box watching for enter, not Google) and it didn't work on Selenium RC, I'm now porting my tests to the new, poorly documented webdriver API.